# Connecting to a remote db through a jump server in Django

Tags: django, database, postgresql, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel my db connection in a django application through a jump server but can't seem to get it working because django manage.py handles & process the connections.
here's that I have in the settings.py

```
#process ssh_key first
ssh_key= os.getenv('SSH_KEY', '').encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
server ={}
with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
   (os.environ.get('SSH_HOST'),int(os.getenv('SSH_PORT'))),
    ssh_pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(io.StringIO(ssh_key)),
    ssh_username= os.environ.get('SSH_USERNAME'),
    remote_bind_address=(os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),  int(os.getenv('DB_PORT'))),
) as ssh_proxy_host: 
    server={
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST':  'localhost',
        'PORT':  ssh_proxy_host.local_bind_port,
        'NAME':  os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER':  os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD':  os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
    }
   # here's where I should have the connection function to db, but don't know if django has that option available
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the error I'm getting is 
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 55437

Comment: DO you need this only for development? or do you want it for your deployment also?

Comment: For dev only. Also, this is a docker application

Comment: Hi @kcodex Were you able to resolve this? I also can't connect to remote DB using SSH jump server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I moved into a new project without getting a work around

Answer (score 0):

The true remote host is specified upon tunnel creation.  The HOST used for the db connection should be `localhost` because you need it to find *your* end of the tunnel, not the other end of it.

Comment: still doesn't work